# Retrieve Customers with a Monthly Order Frequency greater than 4

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, frequency, orders

I am trying to optimize the below query to help fetch all customers **in the last three months** who have a monthly order frequency **+4** for the past three months.

| Customer ID | Feb | Mar | Apr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 0002 | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 0003 | 4 | 2 | 3 |

In the above table, the customer with Customer ID **0001** should only be picked, as he consistently has 4 or more orders in a month.

Below is a query I have written, which pulls all customers with an average purchase frequency of 4 in the last 90 days, but not considering there is a consistent purchase of 4 or more last three months.

Query:

```
SELECT distinct lines.customer_id Customer_ID, (COUNT(lines.order_id)/90) PurchaseFrequency
from fct_customer_order_lines lines
LEFT JOIN product_table product
ON lines.entity_id= product.entity_id
AND lines.vendor_id= product.vendor_id
WHERE LOWER(product.country_code)= "IN"
AND lines.date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE() , INTERVAL 90 DAY )
AND lines.date < CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY Customer_ID
HAVING PurchaseFrequency >=4;
```

I tried to use window functions, however not sure if it needs to be used in this case.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would sum the orders per month instead of computing the avg and then retrieve those who have that sum greater than 4 in the last three months.

Also I think you should select your interval using "month(CURRENT_DATE()) - 3" instead of using a window of 90 days. Of course if needed you should handle the case of when current_date is jan-feb-mar and in that case go back to oct-nov-dec of the previous year.

I'm not familiar with Google BigQuery so I can't write your query but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks there! I have worked on it and found the correct solution using the WITH operator in Big Query. I shall post the query here for future reference !

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the solution to this using WITH operator as below:

```
WITH filtered_orders AS (
   select
  distinct customer_id ID,
  extract(MONTH from date) Order_Month,
  count(order_id) CountofOrders
  from customer_order_lines` lines
  where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = 2022 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) IN (2,3,4)
  group by ID, Order_Month
  having CountofOrders>=4)
select distinct ID
from filtered_orders 
group by ID
having count(Order_Month) =3;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

An option could be first count the orders by month and then filter users which have purchases on all months above your threshold:

```sql
WITH ORDERS_BY_MONTH AS (
    SELECT 
        DATE_TRUNC(lines.date, MONTH) PurchaseMonth,
        lines.customer_id Customer_ID, 
        COUNT(lines.order_id) PurchaseFrequency
    FROM fct_customer_order_lines lines
    LEFT JOIN product_table product
        ON lines.entity_id= product.entity_id
        AND lines.vendor_id= product.vendor_id
    WHERE LOWER(product.country_code)= "IN"
        AND lines.date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE() , INTERVAL 90 DAY )
        AND lines.date < CURRENT_DATE()
    GROUP BY PurchaseMonth, Customer_ID
)
SELECT 
    Customer_ID,
    AVG(PurchaseFrequency) AvgPurchaseFrequency
FROM ORDERS_BY_MONTH
GROUP BY Customer_ID
HAVING COUNT(1) = COUNTIF(PurchaseFrequency >= 4)
```